# Compilation Error when running ASP Web Application in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting error code -2147024888 when running my vb.net web application solution. I tried searching the net for troubleshooting tips but on the scenarios I saw, it happened when the web application is already up in the IIS Server, and never with the same error code.

Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Clear Asp.Net Temp files and Change Application pool in IIS.

Comment: Application Pool in IIS? I am encountering the error when running the code in Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe upgrade to Framework 4.5?